# I'm reading the book the self taught programmer ch17 and I can't figure out why this dosn't work

Tags: python

match Multiple lines

```
import re
zen = """Although never is often better than *right* now. If the implementation
is hard to explain, it's a bad idea. If the implementation is easy to explain, it
may be a good idea. Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
m = re.findall("^If", zen, re.MULTILINE)
print(m)
```

`[if,if]` is what is supposed to print but all I get is `[]`

Comment: Are you sure you copied the example correctly? It will only match `If` at the beginning of a line, but those words are both in the middle of lines.

Comment: use `m = re.findall("If", zen, re.MULTILINE)`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't copy the example correctly. `^` matches the beginning of a line when you use the `re.MULTILINE` flag, so this only matches `If` when it's at the beginning of a line. I don't have the book, but I assume it has each sentence on its own line.

```
import re
zen = """Although never is often better than *right* now. 
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea. 
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea. 
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"""
m = re.findall("^If", zen, re.MULTILINE)
print(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

The caret character `^` means that `If` has to be at the beginning of a line. Remove it and you will get the answer you want.

```
import re
zen = """Although never is often better than *right* now. If the implementation
is hard to explain, it's a bad idea. If the implementation is easy to explain, it
may be a good idea. Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those! """
m = re.findall("If", zen, re.MULTILINE)
print(m)
```

Comment: The example seems to be demonstrating the use of `re.MULTILINE`, removing the `^` makes that meaningless.

Comment: @Barmar I disagree. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html. I also tested it in Python 3.7.4.

Comment: It will work, it's just not the correct fix in this case.

Comment: You'll get the same answer without `re.MULTILINE`.

Comment: This isn't code the user wrote, it's code from a textbook that's trying to teach something specific. Your change doesn't teach the same thing.

Comment: Fair enough. I've never heard of the book and was just looking at the code.

Comment: I've never heard of it either, but what does that matter.  What else would be the point of using `re.MULTILINE` in an example unless you want to demonstrate the effect it has on `^`?

Answer (score 0):

The actual Zen of Python has one sentence per line:

```
zen = """
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"""
m = re.findall("^If", zen, re.MULTILINE)
print(m)
```